# Less resources for steady client connections, why?

Tags: node.js, long-polling

I heard of node.js is very suitable for applications where a persistent connection from the browser to the server is needed. That "long-polling" technique is used, that allows to send updates to the user in real time without needing a lot of server resources. A more traditional server model would need a thread for every single user.

My question, what is done instead, how are the requests served differently?
Why doesn't it take so much resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs is event-driven. The node script is started and then loops continuously, waiting for events to be fired, until stopped. Once running, the overhead associated with loading is done.

Compare this to a more traditional language such as c#.net or PHP, where a request causes the server to load and run the script and it's dependencies. The script then does its' task (often serving a web page) and then shuts down. Another page is requested, the whole process starts again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to server things. So a node server loads possible action that could be needed to serve a task to react to a request?

Comment: note: there are similar event-driven frameworks for python or ruby.